# Changing rectangle dimensions in d3 zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

I am using d3 to build a piano roll editor (which looks kind of like [this](http://www.arsvcs.demon.co.uk/rci/sound/anthem/pete/gfx/screens/piano.gif)). I need the rectangles to always be snapped onto the grid so when I pan or zoom the shapes will stay relative to the grid lines. It doesn't matter if the vertical grid lines redraw as I move in and out, but the number of horizontal grid lines should always stay the same, and the rectangle shapes are always locked on. An example of it not quite working can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/jgab3103/e05qj4hy/

I can see lots of d3 zoom type of examples around the place but I can't find anything to address this kind of issue. I think I am just not understanding how to scale shapes properly when working with the the zoom function. Also, in trying to get this to work I am noticing the panning and zooming seems to have become a bit unreliable, not sure why.

Anyway, if anyone had any ideas on how to solve this, it would be greatly appreciated. The code which is on the jsfiddle is below:

UPDATE: Just to (hopefully!) clarify -  both horizontal and vertical axis need to zoom. The constraint is that the number of horizontal grid lines needs to stay the same and the shapes must be locked on to the grid lines so the dimensions never change. If a rectangle starts with a width and height of 1, this always needs to be retained when zooming.

```
//Data for note shapes
var noteData = [
          {frequency: 3, duration:1, startPoint: 1},
          {frequency: 6, duration:1, startPoint: 2},
          {frequency: 5, duration:1, startPoint: 3},
          {frequency: 4, duration:1, startPoint: 4}
          ];

margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 45
};

width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right;
height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


//SCALES
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,width])
    .range([0, width])


var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,width])
    .range([0, height]);

var heightScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,100])
    .range([0,height]);

//Set up zoom 

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(xScale)
    .y(yScale)
    .scaleExtent([1,100])
    .scale([50])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

// Create SVG space and centre it
svg = d3.select('#chart')
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(zoom);
// Append a rect on top
var rect = svg.append("svg:rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("class", "plot");



var noteRange = d3.range(0,88);
var measureRange = d3.range(0,16);


var make_x_axis = function () {
    return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(10);
};




var make_y_axis = function () {
    return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient("left")
        .tickValues(noteRange);
};

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(10);
    //.tickValues([2,5,7,9]);

svg.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left")
    .tickValues(noteRange);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x grid")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(make_x_axis()
    .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
    .tickFormat(""));

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y grid")
    .call(make_y_axis()
    .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
    .tickFormat(""));

var clip = svg.append("svg:clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("svg:rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var chartBody = svg.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");


var rectGroup = svg.append("g")


var notes = rectGroup
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(noteData)
        .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x",function(d){
              return xScale(d.startPoint)
            })
            .attr("y",function(d){
              return yScale(d.frequency)
            })
            .attr("width",function(d) {
              return 50;
            })
            .attr('class', 'rect')
            .attr("height", function(d) {
              return 23;
            })


function zoomed() {
    svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
    svg.select(".x.grid")
        .call(make_x_axis()
        .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
        .tickFormat(""));
    svg.select(".y.grid")
        .call(make_y_axis()
        .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
        .tickFormat(""));

    rectGroup.selectAll("rect")
         .attr('class', 'rect')
         .attr("x",function(d){
          return xScale(d.startPoint);
        })
         .attr("y",function(d){
          return yScale(d.frequency);
        })
         .attr('width', function(d) {
          return 50;
        })
        .attr("height", function(d) {
              return 23;
            })



}
```

Comment: Do you want to zoom the horizontal axis and leave the vertical axis scale unchanged?

Comment: It's probably unrelated to your problems, but why are you using one set of D3 axes for the visual axes and creating a completely new set of axes for the grid on every zoom?

Comment: As an aside, you can refactor this code to remove a lot of duplication and make it much easier for yourself and others on StackOverflow to see what's going on.

Comment: Sorry I am probably explaining this badly. I am happy for both horizontal and vertical axis to zoom. The constraint is that the number of horizontal grid lines needs to stay the same and the shapes must be locked on to the grid lines so the shape dimensions never change. The problem is that when I zoom the shapes don't stay in the right dimensions (i.e. retain the width and height they started with). I have updated the fiddle above to make it a little more intuitive. You can see the bottom rectangle starts with a height and width of 1 it is no longer snapped to the grid lines.

Comment: @Couchand - I am creating the new axes as I don't really know enough about this! will try and refactor the code

Comment: You've mentioned several constraints and I'm not sure they can all be held at the same time.  With regards to the shapes, it sounds like you want them to both 1) retain their original dimensions, and 2) to remain locked on the grid lines.  I don't see how these can both be satisfied, since as you zoom the grid lines will move together or apart.

Comment: Concerning the grid lines, it sounds like you want the dimension they represent to zoom but also always show the same number of gridlines.  So if, for instance, the vertical dimension initially shows the range 1-4, with four horizontal gridlines on 1, 2, 3 and 4, and the user zooms in such that the vertical dimension now shows the range 2-3, you want there to still be four gridlines, at possibly 2, 2.333, 2.666 and 3?

Comment: Thanks for bearing with this question, as I know I am being too ambiguous. A much simpler way of stating the issue might just be to say: how do I ensure these rectangles are scaled in the same way as the grid lines? 
So in the js fiddle, when you first look at the rectangle on the left, it has a height between 3 and 4, and a width between 1 and 2. But as soon as I start zooming this does not hold. I think its just a matter of me not getting some simple principles with d3 scaling. I am happy with the way the gridlines are behaving, its just how the shapes rescale when I zoom.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want `yScale` to be updated by the zoom behavior, just remove the line `.y(yScale)` and you should be good to go.

The zoom behavior will be constructed simply:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(xScale)
    .scaleExtent([1,100])
    .scale([50])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);
```

and it will only update the `xScale`.